# Openstreetmap Geocoding with housenumber in query

Tags: openstreetmap

For some geocoding data i use OpenStreetMap.

My adresses are located in germany. The big problem with openstreetmap is, that i have problems to search with my housenumber. The Documentation says that the format is

Because of this my searchquery is:

**5 Glogauerstraße**

The result is the following:
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/?format=xml&addressdetails=1&limit=10&q=5%20Glogauerstra%C3%9Fe

This is cool, but there are a lot of results because in germany are a lot of adresses like this. so i will add that this adress must be in BERLIN with the ZIP-Code 10999.

New search-Query:
**5 Glogauerstraße, Berlin 10999**

Now the result is:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/?format=xml&addressdetails=1&limit=10&q=5%20Glogauerstra%C3%9Fe,%20Berlin%2010999

This is nice! Now there is just 1 result!

But the problem is that in this result there isnt the housenumber 5 i was searched for. So the query just "delete" the information of the housenumber.

How can i solve this search query like the way i need it ? Its a big confusing why the openstreet map just delete this information ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but apparently (after searching for the address in the OSM map) OpenStreetMap does not know the housenumbers in this street.

It can correctly geocode this address to approximately accurate coordinates, it is just not accurate enough to know where the house 5 is.

You could possibly try Google Maps services, in my experience it is more accurate in most places.

Comment: Oh, youre right! I did not see that in the results also the Berlin result is missing! I thougth, that OSM already knows where the house number 5 is. Thank you and sorry for my mistake.

Comment: +1 but -1 for trying Google Maps instead just fix the house number(s) for that street in OpenStreetMap please :) !

Comment: Yep. If you know where the house number 5 is then please contribute your knowledge to OSM. Registering and adding a house number is easy :)